# Rendering glDatePicker to dynamically changed date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `glDatePicker` plugin.

To change dynamically selected date I call following code where **dateDepartureVar** is the constructor of `glDatePicker` object.

```
dateDepartureVar.options.selectedDate = new Date(2015, 9, 18);
dateDepartureVar.render();
```

This code changes the `selectedDate` however when the calendar is opened again, it does not open on the selectedDate, it opens wherever it was left off before.

I need the calendar to open exactly on selectedDate. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, obtaining an instance of gldatepicker doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Please verify you have correctly obtained an instance of the datepicker when you initialized. here's an excerpt (slightly edited) from the official documentation :

> When attaching your input, you can pass true to the second call to the glDatePicker constructor to get an instance of glDatePicker returned. You can also do this while chaining with options:

```
// Doing it in a single pass
var dateDepartureVar = $('#example1').glDatePicker(
{
  showAlways: true,
  selectableDOW: [0, 2, 3]
}).glDatePicker(true);  //Pass true here
```

More info [here](http://glad.github.io/glDatePicker/#reference) (official docs)

Comment: Yes I have that in place. Its strange the selectedDate does in fact change (set date is glowing) however it does not place the view over the appropriate month of selected date for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

*The trick is set firstDate too.*

```
$('select[name="monthSelect"]').change(function() {
    let newDate = new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(), parseInt($(this).val())-1, 1);

    $.extend(calendar.options, {
        selectedDate: newDate,
        firstDate: newDate
    });
    calendar.render();
});
```